# Android Changing a TextView within a onClickListener requires a final declaration?

Tags: java, android, final

So I'm trying to get the user to be able to set an onClickListener on a button which will change a TextView upon clicking. However, this causes a final declaration error to appear because I am calling it from an inner class. I don't understand why it requires it to be set to a final, unchangeable variable. I just want the Textview to accept the setText method on an onclick, but when using fragments it prevents me from doing so.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.flash_fragment, container, false);

    Button reply = (Button) v2.findViewById(R.id.replyB);

    TextView flashtext = (TextView) v2.findViewById(R.id.flashtext);

    flashtext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //start playing the string word by word
            //on the textview : flashtext
            ***flashtext.setText("test");***
        }
    });
```

Comment: I've always just made a copy of the variable within the inner class that is final, if the original can't be final for your code.

Comment: I cant seem to set the variable to be final since the LayoutInflator variable is being sent into the onCreateView method and I can't set inflater to be final.

Comment: What about using v, or maybe "this"? v is the View that was passed in the onClick, and I think "this" would be the button as well.

Comment: Just declare `flashText` as `final`. Inside the OnClick `this` is the listener itself. If you use `v`, it would need to be casted as a TextView, then you can call `setText`,

Comment: Also, `final` means the variable assignment is unchangeable, not the object itself.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand why it requires it to be set to a final, unchangeable variable

Because `flashtext` goes out of scope as soon as `onCreateView()` returns. It is a local variable, so that reference lives only for the duration of the `onCreateView()` call.

If you wish to use `flashtext` just from that listener, using `final` is simplest approach.

If you wish to use `flashtext` elsewhere in this fragment, make `flashtext` be a field on your `Fragment` subclass.